# On the elliptic regularity theory of a Schrödinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Let $u\not\equiv0$ be a non-negative solution of the following equation:
$$
-\Delta u+u=|u|^{p-2}u,\quad u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N),
$$
where $N\geq3$ and $2<p<2^*=2N/(N-2)$. My goal is to prove that $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$. The following is my attempt.

First, since $-\Delta u=au$, where $a=|u|^{p-2}-1\in L_{\text{loc}}^{N/2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then by Brezis-Kato theorem, we know $u \in L_{\text{loc}}^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for all $1 \leq p< \infty$ and then $u \in W_{\text{loc}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ by standard $W^{2,p}$ estimate. Then we know $u\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. But how to deduce the $C^2$ regularity? I looked up many books, but I didn't find a similar theorem.

Could anyone please show my a related reference or give some hints of this problem? I'll appreciated it a lot!

Comment: What is $2^{*}$ supposed to mean?

Comment: I'll edit it. $2^*$ is the Sobolev critical exponent

Comment: This result is believable. In the worst possible case ($2<p<3$), if $f(z) = z \vert z \vert^{p-2}-z$ then $f\in C^{1,\alpha}(\mathbb R)$ for some $\alpha>0$. Since $u \in C^1$, $g(x):= f(u(x))$ is $C^{0,1-\varepsilon}$ for all $\varepsilon >0$ so regularity theory gives $u \in C^{2,1-\varepsilon}$

Comment: I would recommend considering a difference quotient to try make the above argument rigorous. I'll have a think about it and maybe post an answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @JackT ! Is the regularity theory you mentioned above Schauder estimate?

Comment: @Frankie Yes that's right. The technique I described above is called bootstrapping. If you are unfamiliar with this I'd recommend looking at p.73-74 in https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf which gives a nice description of the method in the context of Hilberts XIXth problem